# splitting one sheet over multiple pages

Tags: database, excel, sorting

I have an excel spreadsheet that tables multiple things, but from that one sheet i have multiple tabs that need to get the information from the first tab.

Example:

```
Mel     Sydney      12-Jun
Mel     Sydney      12-Jun
Stacy   Melbourne   12-Jun
Matt    Brisbane    12-Jun
Amy     Perth       13-Jun
Matt    Brisbane    13-Jun
David   Adelaide    13-Jun
Mel     Perth       14-Jun
Amy     Perth       14-Jun
Steph   Darwin      14-Jun
```

This would be the first tab. The following tabs would be set by city and will need to search the above table for occurrences of "Sydney" then place a copy of that row into the "Sydney" tab. 
I have managed to do this by using IF command but it leaves gaps where Sydney did not occur. Is there a way to search for "Sydney" if not found move to next line and search for "Sydney", thus leaving no blank lines on the secondary tabs.
If there is a way to do this without using VBN code would be great as i have no idea how to use that.

Comment: I think you're looking for a macro. You could easily loop through your data on City in Sheet1 and create a new tab and copy the data into it for each unique city, or you could check the cities and pick a predefined tab, endless possibilties! :D

Comment: Thanks t.thielemans but i dont quite understand what you mean i can run a macro but i would still need a formula in each line for the macro equation. which would lead to the same result. Are you able to put the equation example in to show me what i am aiming at?